# Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead. Problem reading JSON

Tags: json, swift, api, decode

I know there are some similar questions but its JSONs can't be viewed to be compared with mine.
my JSON:
https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js
my code:

```
struct CoinData: Decodable {
    let Valute: [Valute]
}

struct Valute: Decodable {
    let Name: String
    let Value: Double
}
```

```
if let safeData = data {
    if let coinData = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
    print(coinData) // I expect a list of all the currencies to be printed here
    }
}
```

```
 func parseJSON(_ data: Data) -> [Valute]? {
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CoinData.self, from: data)
            let coinsList = decodedData.Valute
            return coinsList
            
        } catch {
            delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

my error:

```
"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."
```

What should be changed?

Comment: How are you trying to decode that response? Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what it wrote: "error ... found dictionary" -> decode by dictionary:

```
struct CoinData: Decodable {
    let valute: [String: Valute]
}

struct Valute: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let value: Double
}
```

Comment: well, that was simple. Thank you!